# Can't connect to database using visual studios

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a database that I know for a fact I can connect to.  I have used odbc - > I got to system DSN -> I put in all of my credentials and it can test connect ok, but whenever I try to refresh the database in Data Connections in visual studios it states Server Explorer is unable to perform this operation.  A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. I have checked the user name and the password in the connection string, and it's all correct.  Is there anything else that could be done to try and connect with visual studios I may be forgetting. The string in web.config is :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=*********;
Initial Catalog=*******Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User
 ID=********;Password=**********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have tried to disable my firewall as well

when i run the code it will not open that user suggested.  AT the code:
cnn.Open();
It will crash.  The message it gives is:

```
>Can not open connection ! System.Data.SqlClent.SqlException (Ox80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL 
Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: 
Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) System.ComponentModel.Wn32Exception (Ox80004005): The netvvork path was not 
found 
at System. Data.SqlClent.SqIInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action' 1 wrapCloseInAction) 
at System. Data.SqlC5ent.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) 
at System.Data.SqlClent.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverlnfo, SqIInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTlmeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean 
encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedsecurity, Boolean wthFailover) 
at System.Data.SqlClent.SqIInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverlnfo, String newPassword, Securestring newSecurePassword, Boolean 
ignoreSniOpenTlmeout, TimeoutTlmer timeout, Boolean wthFailover) 
at System.Data.SqlClent.SqIInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverlnfo, String newPassword, Securestring newSecurePassword, Boolean 
redirecteduserlnstance, SqlConnectionString connectionoptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTlmer timeout) 
at System. Data.SqlClent.SqIInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnfist(TlmeoutTlmer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionoptions, SqlCredential credential, String 
newPassword, Securestring newSecurePassword, Boolean redirecteduserlnstance) 
at System. Data.SqlClent.SqIInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPooIIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionoptions, SqlCredential credential, Object 
providerlnfo, String newPassword, Securestring newSecurePassword, Boolean redirecteduserlnstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData 
reconnectSessionData) 
at System. Data.SqlClent.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object pooGroupProviderInfo, 
DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions useroptions) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningobject, DbConnectionOptions options, 
DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions useroptions) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningobject, DbConnectionOptions useroptions, Dbconnectionlnternal oldConnection) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningobject, DbConnectionOptions useroptions, Dbconnectionlnternal 
oldConnection) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningobject, Ulnt32 waitForMuttipleObjectsTmeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean 
ontyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions useroptions, Dbconnectionlnternal& connection) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningobject, Taskcompletionsource' 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions useroptions, 
Dbconnectionlnternal& connection) 
at System.Data.Provider3ase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, Taskcompletionsource' 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions 
useroptions, Dbconnectionlnternal oldConnection, Dbconnectionlnternal& connection) 
at System. Data. Provider3ase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
Taskcompletionsource' 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions useroptions) 
at System. Data. Provider3ase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
Taskcompletionsource' 1 retry, DbConnectionOptions useroptions) 
at System. Data.SqlC5ent.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource' 1 retry) 
at System. Data.SqC5ent.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource' 1 retry) 
at System. Data.SqlClent.SqlConnection.Open() 
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-00000000000
```

Comment: This might seem a bit silly. Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? Sometimes stuff just don't work when it should. A restart usually fixes that :)

Comment: Show your code as well you may get some help.

Comment: Your error message indicates its using named pipes. Perhaps named pipes are turned off on the server side. Possibly your ODBC is using TCP/IP instead of named pipes. Have you tried using a UDL instead of an ODBC to test?

Answer (score 0):

try.. like this. and find the Error, what it's says??

```
string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
```

Comment: yes,why not?
if not connected then it's show in catch block.

Comment: when i run the code it will not open.  AT the code:
cnn.Open();

Comment: I put it in the main comment

Answer (score 0):

I did use UDL and it worked. I'm sad to say, but the answer was very simple. I had to do was:

```
Data Source = Server_Name.com
```

instead of Server_Name. It's a real database so I was trying to protect it, but that's where the problem was! Thanks so much for telling me that it was a problem with the name, that's what helped me to figure it out. 
Thank you user/Nick for helping me to narrow down the problem